# How to Result two field with a case query in neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, case

As question, I want to return a result with two field using case, example:

```
CASE WHEN {userid} = {myuserid} THEN true, true AS can_edit, can_delete
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're already working with booleans, then there's no need for CASE at all.

```
...
WITH {userid} = {myuserid} as can_edit
WITH can_edit, can_edit as can_delete
...
```

You could repeat the same comparison again if you really want, though.

As to the question about using CASE for multiple values, you could always use a list or a object to hold the two booleans at the same time.

Something like:

```
...
CASE WHEN {userid} = {myuserid} THEN {can_edit:true, can_delete:true} END AS permissions
```